# Unable to deploy firestore cloud function problem after upgrade from node.js 8 to node.js 10

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Within the packages.json, I have the engines bit changed from "8" to "10".

```
"scripts": {
     "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "submodule:init": "git submodule update --init --recursive",
    "submodule:update": "git submodule update --init --recursive --remote",
    "prepare:submodule": "cross-env-shell node $npm_package_submodule_location/$npm_package_submodule_name/git-scripts/ensure-submodule-integrity.js",
    "check:submodule-status:clean": "cross-env-shell git submodule foreach node ../$npm_package_submodule_name/git-scripts/check-clean.js",
    "check:submodule-status:un-pushed": "cross-env-shell git submodule foreach node ../$npm_package_submodule_name/git-scripts/check-unpushed.js",
    "postinstall-ci": "npm run postinstall",
    "postinstall": "npm run submodule:init && cross-env-shell npm run prepare:submodule && git submodule foreach npm ci"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "10"
},
```

during deployment by running `firebase deploy --only functions`

I have the following error when it hits the "postinstall" process

```
Build failed: sh: 1: cross-env-shell: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! functions@0.1.1-dev.8 postinstall: `npm run submodule:init && cross-env-shell npm run prepare:submodule && git submodule foreach npm ci`
```

I did remove node_module from both main module and submodule and did `npm install` before I deploy but still having the same issue

Comment: try with nodejs 12

Comment: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. The only valid choices are: {"node": 
"8"} and {"node": "10"}.

Comment: You may also find help here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: Any update on this?